# Login using Multiple tables C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Im trying to work out how to use data from 3 tables to authenticate then redirect to a different page dependant on table used. I have the first bit working (ie using 1 table) the problem is when i try to use 2/3 tables.

(I know about SQL injection etc ive just made the page super simple to try and get this working first :))

any help would be really appricated as its driving me nuts

heres were im up to

```
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void _login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Testconnection"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    string Checkuser = "Select count(*) from dbo.loginuser where username='" + Textusername.Text + "'";
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(Checkuser, conn);
    int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    conn.Close();
    if (temp == 1)
    {
        conn.Open();
        string checkPasswordQuery = "select password from dbo.loginuser where username='" + Textusername.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand passComm = new SqlCommand(checkPasswordQuery, conn);
        string password = passComm.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" ", "");
        if (password == textpassword.Text)
        {
            Session["New"] = Textusername.Text;
            Response.Redirect("Reporthome.aspx");
        }

    }
    else
    {
        conn.Open();
        string Checkuser1 = "Select count(*) from dbo.employee where idno='" + Textusername.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand(Checkuser1, conn);
        int temp1 = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        conn.Close();
        if (temp1 == 1)
        {
            conn.Open();
            string checkPasswordQuery1 = "select epass from dbo.employee where idno='" + Textusername.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand passComm1 = new SqlCommand(checkPasswordQuery1, conn);
            string epass = passComm1.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" ", "");
            if (epass == textpassword.Text)
            {
                Session["New"] = Textusername.Text;
                Response.Redirect("Engineerhome.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("password is incorrect");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: "The problem is when I try to use tables 2/3"... what are the 2/3rd tables and what exactly is "the problem"?

Comment: Do you also know about not storing plain password in database?

Comment: This is a mess. You are hitting the same table multiple times. The first query to look at the username, then you query for the same row again to check the password. This whole thing can and should be done in a single select statement. As a side note, you should not be storing passwords in plain text, they should be hashed and salted.

Comment: And this line: int temp1 = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString()); in the "else" statement should probably be int temp1 = Convert.ToInt32(com1.ExecuteScalar().ToString()); (using the wrong command object).

Comment: To take it a bit further, the `ToString()` is superfluous. `ExecuteScalar` returns an object which can be converted directly: `int temp1 = Convert.ToInt32(com1.ExecuteScalar());`

Comment: Thanks Ron Convert.ToInt32(com1.ExecuteScalar().ToString()); fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try and use a stored procedure and let the database handle it.  If the three tables have the same columns or fields then UNION ALL for all three tables and pass your credentials to the stored procedure.

Handle the entire three tables in the select.  Also make sure once you get there to salt your passwords and encrypt accordingly and save the product.

Try something like.....

```
public class PasswordHash{

public static final String PBKDF2_ALGORITHM = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1";

// The following constants may be changed without breaking existing hashes.
public static final int SALT_BYTE_SIZE = 24;
public static final int HASH_BYTE_SIZE = 24;
public static final int PBKDF2_ITERATIONS = 1000;

public static final int ITERATION_INDEX = 0;
public static final int SALT_INDEX = 1;
public static final int PBKDF2_INDEX = 2;

/**
 * Returns a salted PBKDF2 hash of the password.
 *
 * @param   password    the password to hash
 * @return              a salted PBKDF2 hash of the password
 */
public static String createHash(String password)
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException
{
    return createHash(password.toCharArray());
}

/**
 * Returns a salted PBKDF2 hash of the password.
 *
 * @param   password    the password to hash
 * @return              a salted PBKDF2 hash of the password
 */
public static String createHash(char[] password)
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException
{
    // Generate a random salt
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] salt = new byte[SALT_BYTE_SIZE];
    random.nextBytes(salt);

    // Hash the password
    byte[] hash = pbkdf2(password, salt, PBKDF2_ITERATIONS, HASH_BYTE_SIZE);
    // format iterations:salt:hash
    return PBKDF2_ITERATIONS + ":" + toHex(salt) + ":" +  toHex(hash);
}

/**
 * Validates a password using a hash.
 *
 * @param   password        the password to check
 * @param   correctHash     the hash of the valid password
 * @return                  true if the password is correct, false if not
 */
public static boolean validatePassword(String password, String correctHash)
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException
{
    return validatePassword(password.toCharArray(), correctHash);
}

/**
 * Validates a password using a hash.
 *
 * @param   password        the password to check
 * @param   correctHash     the hash of the valid password
 * @return                  true if the password is correct, false if not
 */
public static boolean validatePassword(char[] password, String correctHash)
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException
{
    // Decode the hash into its parameters
    String[] params = correctHash.split(":");
    int iterations = Integer.parseInt(params[ITERATION_INDEX]);
    byte[] salt = fromHex(params[SALT_INDEX]);
    byte[] hash = fromHex(params[PBKDF2_INDEX]);
    // Compute the hash of the provided password, using the same salt, 
    // iteration count, and hash length
    byte[] testHash = pbkdf2(password, salt, iterations, hash.length);
    // Compare the hashes in constant time. The password is correct if
    // both hashes match.
    return slowEquals(hash, testHash);
}

/**
 * Compares two byte arrays in length-constant time. This comparison method
 * is used so that password hashes cannot be extracted from an on-line 
 * system using a timing attack and then attacked off-line.
 * 
 * @param   a       the first byte array
 * @param   b       the second byte array 
 * @return          true if both byte arrays are the same, false if not
 */
private static boolean slowEquals(byte[] a, byte[] b)
{
    int diff = a.length ^ b.length;
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length && i < b.length; i++)
        diff |= a[i] ^ b[i];
    return diff == 0;
}

/**
 *  Computes the PBKDF2 hash of a password.
 *
 * @param   password    the password to hash.
 * @param   salt        the salt
 * @param   iterations  the iteration count (slowness factor)
 * @param   bytes       the length of the hash to compute in bytes
 * @return              the PBDKF2 hash of the password
 */
private static byte[] pbkdf2(char[] password, byte[] salt, int iterations, int bytes)
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException
{
    PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, iterations, bytes * 8);
    SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(PBKDF2_ALGORITHM);
    return skf.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
}

/**
 * Converts a string of hexadecimal characters into a byte array.
 *
 * @param   hex         the hex string
 * @return              the hex string decoded into a byte array
 */
private static byte[] fromHex(String hex)
{
    byte[] binary = new byte[hex.length() / 2];
    for(int i = 0; i < binary.length; i++)
    {
        binary[i] = (byte)Integer.parseInt(hex.substring(2*i, 2*i+2), 16);
    }
    return binary;
}

/**
 * Converts a byte array into a hexadecimal string.
 *
 * @param   array       the byte array to convert
 * @return              a length*2 character string encoding the byte array
 */
private static String toHex(byte[] array)
{
    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(1, array);
    String hex = bi.toString(16);
    int paddingLength = (array.length * 2) - hex.length();
    if(paddingLength > 0)
        return String.format("%0" + paddingLength + "d", 0) + hex;
    else
        return hex;
}

/**
 * Tests the basic functionality of the PasswordHash class
 *
 * @param   args        ignored
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        // Print out 10 hashes
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            System.out.println(PasswordHash.createHash("p\r\nassw0Rd!"));

        // Test password validation
        boolean failure = false;
        System.out.println("Running tests...");
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            String password = ""+i;
            String hash = createHash(password);
            String secondHash = createHash(password);
            if(hash.equals(secondHash)) {
                System.out.println("FAILURE: TWO HASHES ARE EQUAL!");
                failure = true;
            }
            String wrongPassword = ""+(i+1);
            if(validatePassword(wrongPassword, hash)) {
                System.out.println("FAILURE: WRONG PASSWORD ACCEPTED!");
                failure = true;
            }
            if(!validatePassword(password, hash)) {
                System.out.println("FAILURE: GOOD PASSWORD NOT ACCEPTED!");
                failure = true;
            }
        }
        if(failure)
            System.out.println("TESTS FAILED!");
        else
            System.out.println("TESTS PASSED!");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR: " + ex);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: OP also could use parameterized queries

Answer (score 0):

Since your two coding elements are so similar, you could also create a separate routine that is common to both elements, like this version of `EmpPassword`:

```
private string EmpPassword(string sqlText, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection openConnection)
{
    object obj = null;
    using (var cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sqlText, openConnection))
    {
        using (var r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (r.Read())
            {
                obj = r.GetValue(0);
            }
        }
    }
    if ((obj != null) && (obj != DBNull.Value))
    {
        return obj.ToString().Replace(" ", "");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Your `_login_Click` event could call each of your databases, depending on the outcome, using the same database connection object:

```
protected void _login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Testconnection"].ConnectionString))
    {
        Session["New"] = null;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            var sqlText = String.Format("SELECT password FROM dbo.loginuser WHERE username='{0}';", Textusername.Text);
            var sqlResult = EmpPassword(sqlText, con);
            if (sqlResult == textpassword.Text)
            {
                Session["New"] = Textusername.Text;
                Response.Redirect("Reporthome.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                sqlText = String.Format("Select epass from dbo.employee where idno='{0}';", Textusername.Text);
                sqlResult = EmpPassword(sqlText, con);
                if (sqlResult == textpassword.Text)
                {
                    Session["New"] = Textusername.Text;
                    Response.Redirect("Engineerhome.aspx");
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Write("password is incorrect");
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Notice I skipped the `SELECT Count(*)` options on both. If the user exists on the table, it will be returned.

Of course, if your schema allows multiple instances of the same user ID, that would not work.